# C++ Console INT Input Validation - Detect ENTER before no data entered?

Tags: c++, validation, input

I have this block of code form my input class I wish to improve. It works fine at the moment.

http://ideone.com/ryatJ

You use it like this... What it dose is pass a reference to the stream, and a reference to the userinput and a int to mark the max range the input has to be. The usrinput is referenced so we can use that elsewhere and it returns a true false so we can use it like this.. to get input...

```cpp
while (!(validate(cin, returnval, a))){
        //# Error Code code here
    }
```

Basically everything works.. it asks the user to input a number that we are expecting as a  int.

Using if (cin >> int) - I get a true false based on if the user entered a int or not. (so any string or anything... errors)
Using > and < we make sure the int is in the correct range, or it errors.
Useing peek we check the stream for a \n.. if it is not found.. it errors. (so 2.2 or 2:3 4@3 etc etc will error)

So that is all working, so well in fact I only just recently noticed that there is one more error check I need. Though I am not sure how to do it.

Basically if you just press enter with out first putting in ANY value, cin just goes to a new line. Is there a way to detect that the user just hit enter and nothing else, so I can return teh correct error message and redraw the menu screen and all the other stuff I wish to do.?

SUMMERY

How can I add to this a function to check if enter is pressed with out entering any other vales?

Thanks for the help
--Jynks

EDIT------

I can not answer my own question.. but this is the answer...

I was very close.. but the answer was in my code already.... meaning that cin.peek() is looking at the stream, at the moment it is calling it after it is read into a variable. This means it is seeing the "2nd" char and why the test works... all I needed to do was make a new test b4 the cin was read and it checked the 1st character..

Solved
http://ideone.com/mt7jH

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `peek` at the beginning work? However, I think a better solution would be to read the complete line and parse that.